# Should std::chrono::steady_clock::now be noexcept?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono, noexcept

I've noticed that `std::chrono::steady_clock::now` has the `noexcept` specifier in the documentation at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/steady_clock/now/). However, I haven't found any provision for this in the latest C++11 draft (unfortunately I don't have a copy of the standard).

Is it a mistake in the cplusplus.com documenation or should `std::chrono::steady_clock::now` have the `noexcept` specifier?

Comment: Use http://en.cppreference.com/ as a reference instead.

Comment: Use N3337 as the closest approximation to the C++11 standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

§ 20.11.7.2 of the C++11 standard's definition of `steady_clock`:

```
class steady_clock {
public:
    typedef unspecified rep;
    typedef ratio<unspecified , unspecified > period;
    typedef chrono::duration<rep, period> duration;
    typedef chrono::time_point<unspecified, duration> time_point;
    static const bool is_steady = true;
    static time_point now() noexcept;
};
```

So yes, `std::steady_clock::now()` should be `noexcept` and it isn't an error in the documentation. [It seems cppreference says the same](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock/now).