# How does std::chrono::steady_clock::now report errors?

Tags: c++, c++11, error-handling, c++-chrono

This is related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18109251/471164) where I asked if `std::chrono::steady_clock::now` should be `noexcept`. Now that I know that it should I wonder how does this function report errors? For example, a common implementation of this function on Linux uses 
[clock_gettime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) which can return an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of the errors that could be reported by the Linux `clock_gettime` facility are not possible in a debugged implementation of `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`.

The errors are:

```
int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp);


EFAULT
```

> tp points outside the accessible address space.

There is no user-supplied `tp` to get wrong in `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`.  If `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()` passes the wrong `tp` to `clock_gettime`, it is just a bug in `steady_clock` that is easily fixed.

```
EINVAL
```

> The clk_id specified is not supported on this system.

There is no user-supplied `clk_id` to get wrong in `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`.  If `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()` passes the wrong `clk_id` to `clock_gettime`, it is just a bug in `steady_clock` that must be fixed.

Note that an implementation of `steady_clock` isn't guaranteed to be portable, and may have to be ported to any given platform and be tested for correctness.  It might turn out that `steady_clock` can not be implemented in terms of `clock_gettime` on some platforms.

```
EPERM
```

> clock_settime() does not have permission to set the clock indicated.

Not applicable to `steady_clock` as there is no API to set the time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. What about Windows where the clock is normally implemented using QueryPerformanceCounter which can return an the documentation doesn't seem to enumerate the error cases?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Windows.  I do see this LWG issue, currently in status NAD Future: http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-closed.html#935

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. There's no provision in the API for error reporting. So the Linux implementation must either handle errors internally or not return (e.g., via `exit()` or `std::terminate()`).

Comment: An implementation could also store the last successful value and just return it in case it cannot access a real clock. This satisfies the monotonic requirement of `steady_clock`. I have no idea if any implementations actually do this.

Comment: @GManNickG That would fall under the heading of "handle errors internally" - but it would not conform (at least in principle) to the requirement that "values of `time_point` advance at a steady rate relative to real time." from 20.11.7.2/1 [time.clock.steady].